# Changing Active Directory Root Domain / Forest Domain Name

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, root

I have created an AD Network where the root / forest domain is chicago.mydomain.com. I realized that it should have been best to make the root / forest domain mydomain.com and then create the chicago.mydomain.com domain because it doesn't know how to resolve www.mydomain.com or exchange.mydomain.com, *.mydomain.com, etc.

Does Active Directory Domain Services allow you to change the root/forest domain once it's been created?

Comment: This is very similar to a question you've already asked, so let me ask: Do you have any member servers or computers in this domain yet? Any users? Any resources (Exchange, etc.)? If not it might be easier for you to start from scratch with a new AD domain. If you do, don't use your public domain name for the AD name, use an unused subdomain for AD, such as AD.MYDOMAIN.COM.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I do. I have an exchange server, print server, file server, 3 member computers, and 2 domain controllers. I have several users, but they aren't too important. I feel like it would be complex to reconfigure Exchange.

Comment: If you've already got Exchange Server 2007/2010/2013 in the domain then a domain rename isn't possible. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc738208(v=WS.10).aspx